# Perl Script, Web Scraper

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I have this script which scrapes the amazon website for reviews. Everytime I run it I get an error about a compilation error. Was wondering if someone could shed some light as to whats wrong with it.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/perl
# get_reviews.pl
#
# A script to scrape Amazon, retrieve reviews, and write to a file
# Usage: perl get_reviews.pl <asin>
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

# Take the asin from the command-line
my $asin = shift @ARGV or die "Usage: perl get_reviews.pl <asin>\n";

# Assemble the URL from the passed asin.
my $url = "http://amazon.com/o/tg/detail/-/$asin/?vi=customer-reviews";
  
# Set up unescape-HTML rules. Quicker than URI::Escape.
my %unescape = ('&quot;'=>'"', '&amp;'=>'&', '&nbsp;'=>' ');
my $unescape_re = join '|' => keys %unescape;

# Request the URL.
my $content = get($url);
die "Could not retrieve $url" unless $content;

#Remove everything before the reviews
$content =~ s!.*?Number of Reviews:!!ms;

# Loop through the HTML looking for matches
while ($content =~ m!<img.*?stars-(\d)-0.gif.*?>.*?<b>(.*?)</b>, (.*?)[RETURN]
    \n.*?Reviewer:\n<b>\n(.*?)</b>.*?</table>\n(.*?)<br>\n<br>!mgis) {

  my($rating,$title,$date,$reviewer,$review) = [RETURN] 
  ($1||'',$2||'',$3||'',$4||'',$5||'');
  $reviewer =~ s!<.+?>!!g;   # drop all HTML tags
  $reviewer =~ s!\(.+?\)!!g;   # remove anything in parenthesis
  $reviewer =~ s!\n!!g;      # remove newlines
  $review =~ s!<.+?>!!g;     # drop all HTML tags
  $review =~ s/($unescape_re)/$unescape{$1}/migs; # unescape.

  # Print the results
  print "$title\n" . "$date\n" . "by $reviewer\n" . "$rating stars.\n\n" . "$review\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Could you post more info about the error?

Comment: Basically it says that "Global Symbol "$reviewer" requires explicit package name at C:\User\test.pl line 25. Also a Syntax error near "(" on line 36.

Comment: I know that the global symbol error is because the variable is not properly declared, but I do not get the syntax error.

Comment: @user2916250 There is no `$reviewer` at line 25 and there is no syntax error in the code that you posted. Post the actual code if you want anyone to figure it out

Comment: This is the actual code, I think $reviewer might need to be defined in the top. Like "My $Reviewer".

Answer (score 3):

The syntax errors seem to be caused by the "[RETURN]" that appears twice in your code. When I removed those, the code compiled without problems.

Amazon don't really like people scraping their web site. Which is why they provide an API that gives you access to their content. And there's a Perl module that for using that API - [Net::Amazon](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-Amazon). You should use that instead of fragile web scraping techniques.

Comment: Hmm I thought that Amazon has gotten rid of their API for Customer Reviews? Has this changed? and Thanks for information!

Comment: This page about their API (https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) says "The Product Advertising API helps you advertise Amazon products using product search and look up capability, product information and features such as **Customer Reviews**, Similar Products, Wish Lists and New and Used listings"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try Web::Scraper (http://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper).
It will get the job done in a much cleaner way.

[EDIT] Anyway, I checked the HTML code of a random review and it appears that your pattern is outdated. The reviewer's name, for instance, is introduced by 'By' and not by 'Reviewer'.

Comment: Web::Scraping is a definite improvement on manual regexes, but it's still web scraping. Using Amazon's API is the best solution here.

Comment: I did not know about the API. For this particular task it is definitely the best solution. When no API is available web scrapping module should be considered...